# Getting a pivot table to treat two columns as one

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am fairly new to pivot tables, but with a complex problem, I think.

The scenario is that each application is graded by two assessors, a main and secondary. So let us assume that one assessor is called Maggie, and she is sometimes main, sometimes secondary, likewise with the others. Now I want to use a pivot table to find out the average grades of assessors Maggie, Elsie and Wilma respectively.

Now, if there were only one assessor per application, it would be the simplest thing in the world to summarize the average grade of each assessor. But the snag is that the assessors are spread over two columns.

To illustrate it, you can see a minimal example worksheet:
[image]
(xls: https://ufile.io/uwo32)

How would I go about summarizing the average for each assessor in total, not depending on whether s/he is main or secondary assessor?

Comment: You might take a look at the "Pivot Table from Multiple Consolidation Ranges" section [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot08.html). It'll let you set up a pivot table off multiple ranges, but treat them as one table. Though you'd probably have to split up the columns in your table to make it easier, with one table of Name/Score of main and another with Name/Score of secondary.

Answer (score 0):

You can create [Calculated Field in Pivot Table](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html) too.